# I want to show interstitial between multiple pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, interstitial

I have multiple pages.screen_one and screen_two.First screen_one to screen_two and then i want to show interstitial ad at return from screen_two to screen_one.How do that.

Comment: use `onDispose` for this, launch an interstitial in it.

Comment: Can you share sample code.@meditat

Comment: Somethig like this `@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    //your show interstitial method
    showInterstitial();
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use WillPopScope widget in the top of the widgets tree in the screen two, set a function when the user use the back button, but showing an ad on this is against the admob policy.

```
           return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async {
                    showInterstitial();
                    return null;
                    child: ...
                  },
                );
```